# Prevent turtle from leaving screen?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In this program, the user can control the turtle using the arrow keys, but how can i prevent them from leaving the screen?

```
def h1():
        kjr.forward(20)
    def h2():
        kjr.right(45)
    def h3():
        kjr.left(45)
    wn.onkey(h1, 'Up')
    wn.onkey(h2, 'Right')
    wn.onkey(h3, 'Left')
    wn.listen()
    wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interrogate your `wn` screen variable to find out the height and width of your window (if you don't know it already) and then modify `h1()` to prevent the turtle from wandering outside of those limits.  Here's a simple example that checks after the fact and undoes the move if undesirable:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def h1():
    kjr.forward(20)

    x, y = kjr.position()

    if -width < x < width and -height < y < height:
        return

    kjr.undo()

def h2():
    kjr.right(45)

def h3():
    kjr.left(45)

wn = Screen()

width, height = wn.window_width() / 2, wn.window_height() / 2

kjr = Turtle('turtle')

wn.onkey(h1, 'Up')
wn.onkey(h2, 'Right')
wn.onkey(h3, 'Left')

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

You'll likely want to embellish and polish this a bit.